# Este diagrama de clases es correcto?

Tags: php, mysql, poo, diseño-de-clases

Lo que sucede es que hice un sistema para gestionar una base de datos en MYSQL, con PHP y Mysqli, donde utilizo POO para operar sobre las tablas de la base de datos, pero estas clases no tienen atributos, solo métodos para insertar, consultar, actualizar y eliminar, y solo reciben la conexión de la clase conexión en sus parámetros para conectarse a la base de datos. o igualmente extienden de Conexion, recibiendo el parámetro con la conexion, en cualquier caso

Quiero hacer un diagrama de clases para un manual técnico que describa las clases utilizadas, y obtuve este resultado

La relación en la dependencia es USE, porque el sistema registra las acciones de los usuarios sorbe la base, como agregar, actualizar o eliminar algún registro, y un usuario administrador solo puede ver y vaciar la tabla historial, por eso solo tiene 3 metodos

[image: Diagrama de clases 1]

-> Podrían explicarme si esta estructura estaría bien, o es realmente necesario los demás atributos para las clases que representan las tablas, como id y demás, para que realmente sea POO?

Mis disculpas, pero aun no se implementar correctamente el MVC, por eso aparecen los métodos iniciar y cerrar sesión en la clase usuario.

He visto otros sistemas y crud que lo utilizan así, pero no se cómo podría argumentar a favor de esta forma, por ejemplo: https://github.com/JeniferTriana/CMS_JENIFERTRIANA_1821630/blob/master/models/User.php

Este es el modelo ER con el que trabajo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqJWI.png
Y como es PHP, utilizo el estilo orientado a objetos

Comment: Te dejo una liga donde explican respecto al tema de los diagramas de clases https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/es/tutorial-de-diagrama-de-clases-uml. Compara tu diagrama con los de ejemplo, espero te sea útil.

Comment: vale, pero en su opinión, estaría bien usar las clases así, y el diagrama estaría bien o requiere de atributos :_ ?

Comment: En la descripción de clases del link que te mande indica que pueden o no ir los atributos, Te pongo un ejemplo de mis clases en las respuesta a tu pregunta

Comment: @Cesarin Me dejarías ver una clase tuya?

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un extracto de la explicación de como hacer un diagrama de clases del enlace que te indique:

> Clases: Una plantilla para crear objetos e implementar un
> comportamiento en un sistema. En UML, una clase representa un objeto o
> un conjunto de objetos que comparte una estructura y un comportamiento
> comunes. Se representan con un rectángulo que incluye filas del nombre
> de la clase, sus atributos y sus operaciones. Al dibujar una clase en
> un diagrama de clases, solo se debe cumplimentar la fila superior. Las
> otras son opcionales y se usan si deseas agregar más detalles.
>
> ```
> Nombre: La primera fila en una figura de clase.
>
> Atributos: La segunda fila en una figura de clase. Cada atributo de una clase está ubicado en una línea separada.
>
> Métodos: La tercera fila en una figura de clase. También conocidos como "operaciones", los métodos se organizan en un formato de lista donde cada operación posee su propia línea.
> ```

Como puedes ver indica que pueden ir o no, no esta ni bien o mal, es muy subjetiva la definición o descripción de como hacer una clase,  ya mas bien depende de ti si deseas tener esos datos indicados ahí o que no estén indicados.

Te pongo un extracto de mis clases y te comento al respecto:

[image: Extracto de diagrama de clases]

Se puede observar que si incluí informacion en el espacio de los atributos, para mi y para las dos personas que me solicitaron estos diagramas entendemos al verlos que hay una relación directa entre una clase y otra dependiente de un elemento al menos, por citar un ejemplo usuarios_scp se relaciona con recursos humanos con el elemento +Numero_Empleado y usuarios_scp se relaciona con roles con el elemento +Id_Roles.

Como puedes observar el agregar o no algún elemento es solo un tema del tipo "descriptivo" que le permita a otra persona interpretar como es que una clase depende de la otra, o como es que se relacionan o conectan.

Espero te sea útil esta pequeña intervención.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias @Cesarin, pero que riesgos o desventajas hay en utilizar atributos públicos?

Comment: @JuanSebastianLozanoGarzon Me agarraste en mis 5 minutos no entiendo tu pregunta.

Comment: me refiero a que efectos negativos podría tener en un cms utilizar clases con atributos públicos, sería una buena o mala practica?

Comment: Si te refieres al momento que escribes las clases indicar a cada atributo o propiedad que se pueden definir como "public" "private"y "protected" , no creo que sea buena o mala practica.  Mas bien es en el orden de la idea de como puedes acceder a ese valor.  Te dejo la definicion de "Visibildad"  : https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php                            Yo en este momento a todas mis variables de clases las estoy definiendo como private.

Comment: dices que las variables de tus clases son private, pero en el diagrama que muestras indican que son publicas (+). entonces cual utilizas y por qué?

Comment: Ya tiene tiempo que hice esos diagramas, entre otras cosas fue de rápido que urge que lo presentes, vagamente recuerdo que en algo tenia una restricción el software que utilice para hacer esos diagramas,  a lo mejor fue por eso, pero si tienes razón se tiene que indicar con símbolo menos -, tengo agregar mas clases así que aprovechare para ver si puedo cambiar ese + por un -.  Gracias por la observación.   Lo que me implica que tendré que actualizar el diagrama de objetos tambien  ahhh :)  En fin.  Saludos